# Cross Product - Moments :: Dynamics

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, cross-product

Some background: I am self studying dynamics and I have encountered a fundamental problem with either my understanding of linear algebra, or I am just plain dumb. So, I print screened the page of the book we're on. Now let me try to reduce some ambiguity in my question, since my last one was not clear enough, I have a general understanding of the cross product and unit vectors. With this question it's stating the $G$ is the momentum of the particle is $G = mvn$, where $n$ is the unit vector in the direction of velocity. When we try to take the moment of the position vector from $O$ to $P$ with the momentum we get:

$$
\begin{align}
  M^{G/O}
    &= p^{P/O} \times G=p^{Q/O} \times G \tag{1} & \text{($G/O$ means vector $G$ with respect to $O$)}\\
    &= y_0 n_y \times mv(\cos\theta n_x + \sin \theta n_z) \tag{2}\\
    &= mvy_0(\sin \theta n_x − \cos \theta n_z) \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Questions:

A.] (I figured this one out on my own, look down for my reasoning.) How does $G = mvn$ imply that $G = mv(\cos \theta n_x +  \sin \theta n_z)$?  Or more specifically, how does $n = (\cos \theta n_x + \sin \theta n_z)$.

B.] How do we actually do the cross product on (2) to get to (3) if there are no explicit components of these vectors, B-1]how do you set up the determinant matrix to reach (3).

C.] How does the position vector from O -> P = the position vector from O -> Q if the particle at position P has a position in 3 dimensions, so how is it possible that $$\text{the position vector from O -> Q} = y_0n_y,$$ which is just the the distance $y_0$ in the direction of $n_y$?

---

My solution for the first question, A.]

Since $n$ is pointing in the same direction as velocity and momentum, n can be broken up into its respective components which are simple functions of the angle it makes with the Q axis, so we take the $\cos\theta$ and take the component that is in the $n_x$ direction. Which forms the vector component $(\cos\theta n_x)$, we then add it to the vector component in the $n_z$ direction, $(\sin\theta n_z)$, Therefore, $$ n = (\cos\theta n_x + \sin \theta n_z) $$

---

Here is a link to the pdf of the book if anyone is interested:

[Fundamentals of Applied Dynamics - Tenenbaum](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/P_Physics/PC_Classical%20physics/PCtm_Theoretical%20mechanics/Tenenbaum%20R.A.%20Fundamentals%20of%20applied%20dynamics%20%28Springer,%202004%29%28ISBN%20038700887X%29%28O%29%28730s%29_PCtm_.pdf)

[image: Page 33 of Fundamentals of Applied Dynamics - Tenenbaum]

Comment: Thank you epimorphic for your wonderful edits, maybe someone can answer these questions. I also request a response on my reasoning for (A) as to whether or not it is correct.

Comment: B.] The vectors in line (2) are already expressed in terms of components $\mathbf{n}_x$, $\mathbf{n}_y$, and $\mathbf{n}_z$, no? Then use $\mathbf{n}_y \times \mathbf{n}_x = -\mathbf{n}_z$ and $\mathbf{n}_y \times \mathbf{n}_z = \mathbf{n}_x$.

Comment: C.] $\mathbf{p}^{P/O} \neq \mathbf{p}^{Q/O}$. Instead, $\mathbf{p}^{P/O} = \mathbf{p}^{Q/O} + s\mathbf{n}$ (going by the figure), but Tenenbaum drops the last term because $\mathbf{n}\times\mathbf{G}=\mathbf{n}\times mv\mathbf{n}=0$, I think.

Comment: So for B] you're saying you don't actually cross $$N =((\cos\theta n_x), 0, (\sin\theta n_z))$$ you cross $$n_y$$ with $$n_x$$ and $$n_z$$ and ignore $$y_0$$ and $$mv$$, since they are scalars? And their respective signs for the $$n_x n_y n_z$$ changes the sign of $$\cos\theta and \sin\theta.$$ I don't understand your explanation for C.] But thanks anyway, I'll re-read it a million times. Sorry I'm unfamiliar with Latex so I don't know how to makes this comment neater

Comment: Could you explain the deduction of $$p^((P/O)) = y_0n_y?$$

Comment: You can use inline formulas (`$...$`) instead of displayed formulas (``$$...$$``) unless you have a long or a particularly important formula. For more formatting tips, see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/74908).

Comment: C] $\mathbf{p}^{P/O}=(s \cos \theta, y_0, s \sin \theta) \neq y_0\mathbf{n}_y$.

Comment: B) The cross product is bilinear, which basically means (among other things) that $\mathbf{a}\times(\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c})=\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}$ and $t(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})
=(t\mathbf{a})\times\mathbf{b}
=\mathbf{a}\times(t\mathbf{b})$. Thus, 
\begin{align}
y_0\mathbf{n}_y\times mv(\cos\theta\mathbf{n}_x+\sin\theta\mathbf{n}_z)
&=mvy_0(\mathbf{n}_y\times(\cos\theta\mathbf{n}_x+\sin\theta\mathbf{n}_z))\\
&=mvy_0(\cos\theta(\mathbf{n}_y\times\mathbf{n}_x)+\sin\theta(\mathbf{n}_y\times \mathbf{n}_z))\\
&=mvy_0(-\cos\theta\mathbf{n}_z+\sin\theta\mathbf{n}_x).
\end{align}

Comment: Your comments have been very useful, thank you. One final question, If you wouldn't mind: So $y_0n_y \times mv((\cos\theta n_x + \sin\theta n_z))$   represents the moment of momentum with the position vector from    $$O -> Q$$ Since $y_0 n_y$ is the distance from $O -> Q$ in the direction of $n_y?$ I'm just making sure my understanding is absolutely correct as with self study demands that you have a very precise understanding of these fundamentals since I don't have a teacher.

Comment: I think you meant that $y_0\mathbf{n}_y$ is the *displacement* from $O$ to $P$ in the direction of $\mathbf{n}_y$. Even with the correction, however, the wording seems rather superficial. More fundamentally, the moment $\mathbf{M}^{\mathbf{G}/O}$, defined as $\mathbf{p}^{P/O}\times\mathbf{G}$, is equal to $$\mathbf{p}^{Q/O}\times\mathbf{G}=y_0\mathbf{n}_y\times mv(\cos\theta,0,\sin\theta)$$ because $\mathbf{p}^{Q/O}$ is the [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_projection) of the position vector $\mathbf{p}^{P/O}$ onto the planar subspace perpendicular to $\mathbf{G}$.

Comment: More concretely, if we go back to my second comment, we'd see that $$\mathbf{p}^{P/O}\times\mathbf{G}=(\mathbf{p}^{Q/O}+s\mathbf{n})\times\mathbf{G} = \mathbf{p}^{Q/O}\times\mathbf{G}+s\mathbf{n}\times\mathbf{G} = \mathbf{p}^{Q/O}\times\mathbf{G}+0,$$ because $s\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{G}$ are parallel.